# Determinant error following elementary row operations (4 x 4)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

In calculating the following 4x4 determinant, the value of the determinant is supposedly $ab(ab - cd)$.  However, my determinant calculation is different by a factor of $-g$.  I think I'm making a small algebra error somewhere that my double-checking isn't catching.  If someone could tell me why my development below is incorrect, I would appreciate it.
$$\begin{vmatrix}gc & ge & a+ge & gb+ge \\ 0 & b & b & b \\ c & e & e & b+e \\ a & b & b+f & b+d \end{vmatrix}$$
First, I multiplied Row 3 by *g* and subtracted that from Row 1, placing the new values in Row 3.  This produced three zero entries and one nonzero entry in the new Row 3.
$$\begin{vmatrix}gc & ge & a+ge & gb+ge \\ 0 & b & b & b \\ 0 & 0 & a & 0 \\ a & b & b+f & b+d \end{vmatrix}$$
Expanding the determinant computation about Row 3 above (and then about Column 1 below), I have:
$$=a\begin{vmatrix} gc & ge & gb+ge \\ 0 & b & b \\ a & b & b+d \end{vmatrix} =agc\begin{vmatrix} b & b \\ b & b+d \end{vmatrix}+a^2\begin{vmatrix}ge & gb+ge \\ b & b \end{vmatrix}$$
$$ =agc(b^2+bd-b^2)+a^2(beg-gb^2-beg)=agc(bd)-a^2b^2g=abg(cd-ab) $$
Again, computing the determinant without any row operations or other properties yields $ab(ab - cd)$.  Thanks for finding the error(s).

Comment: You multiplied a row by $g$ in your first step! That will make the determinant $g$ times your original determinant. Otherwise, everything else seems fine.

Comment: I might be inclined to agree with you, except that another person solving the problem also multiplied Row 3 by $g$ and subtracted that from Row 1.  The difference is that they replaced Row 1 with the new result, whereas I kept Row 1 the same and replaced Row 3.  This still leaves the original Row 1 and Row 3 represented in the altered matrix.  Then, how do I explain the different results?

Comment: @daruma Where's his -1 coming from? o.O

Comment: "I multiplied Row 3 by g and subtracted that from Row 1, placing the new values in Row 3" - that doesn't necessarily preserve the determinant. Replacing row 1 with (row 1 minus $g$ times row 3) would preserve the determinant. In general, you can replace row $i$ with (row $i$ + scalar $\times$ row $j$), but you can't replace row $j$ with (row $i$ + scalar $\times$ row $j$).

Comment: More precisely, what you did is equivalent to first multiplying row 3 by $-g$ (which causes the determinant to be scaled by $-g$), and then adding row 1 to row 3 (which does not change the determinant).

Comment: @Bungo  Thank you.  I believe you are correct -- I slightly misinterpreted the wording: "The determinant is unchanged by adding to the elements of one row any fixed multiple of the elements of *another* row."  I multiplied Row 3 by something and added it to Row 1, so I should have replaced Row 1, I'm concluding.  Although, I could have sworn I've computed many determinants correctly without paying close attention to that.

Comment: "so I should have replaced Row 1" - yep, exactly. I'll go ahead and summarize in an answer so this can be marked as resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was introduced here:

> I multiplied Row 3 by $g$ and subtracted that from Row 1, placing the new values in Row 3

That operation doesn't generally preserve the determinant.

If you had placed the result in **row 1** (as opposed to row 3), that would have preserved the determinant. In general, you can replace row $i$ with (row $i$ + scalar $×$ row $j$), but you can't replace row $j$ with (row $i$ + scalar $×$ row $j$).

Putting it another way, what you did is equivalent to first multiplying row 3 by $−g$ (which causes the determinant to be scaled by −g), and then adding row 1 to row 3 (which does not change the determinant). That explains why your answer is in error by a factor of $-g$.